# nvidia GPU and nvidia settings don't work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I recently set up a dual boot on my inspiron 15 7000. On Ubuntu, I can't use the nvidia gpu. When I try to access the nvidia settings, the icon flashes a bit and then stops flashing. I tried installing the drivers by disabling X server and then installing the 390 drivers. When I reboot my laptop, it boots but when I try to log in, the screen goes black and then goes back to the login screen. Purging nvidia using sudo apt-get purge nvidia* fixes this login loop. Anyone have any way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Brendan, what Nvidia video card do you have?

Comment: My laptop has a nvidia 1050 Ti

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by installing the deb network version from here.
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
Hope this helps someone with the same problem.